# Convert IBM .phdfile to .hprof heap dump format

Tags: java, heap-memory, websphere-6.1

I am trying to analyse a dump file from a websphere production machine, at the moment I am not succesfull because the file is of the type .phd, and well things would be alot easier when the file could be converted to .hprof

Answer (score 1):

It is not generally possible to convert a PHD to HProf format.  Have you tried using [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)?

Comment: Yes I did without succes, meanwhile I solved the websphere memory leak issues by connecting jconsole to the vm.

Answer (score 1):

For PHD dumps use JProbe (see http://www.quest.com/jprobe), where you can import IBM PHD Dump files and analyze them. JProbe is a really powerful and easy to use tool for java profiling.
You can also use JProbe plug-in for Eclipse if you like Eclipse environment.
Regards, Lukas.